# How to create a stained glass effect in Photoshop

Tags: background, texture, filter

There are  few ok tuts online, but I haven't found a way to give an image the marblelized clear shiny opacity like real stain glass. Any tips?

1. Stain glass filter applied
2. Lower opacity
3. Play with waves filter?

Answer (score 3):

I think where most of the stained glass tutorials fail is in capturing the irregularities that glass has. Filters work with patterns, and the final result is usually not very realistic. An example of real stained glass:

[image]

When using filters, the result is usually flat. Glass looks sort of the same in the whole window, they loose the craftsmanship beauty the real ones have.

I'd recommend you take a more **photographic** approach to the problem. If you are using Photoshop, instead of recreating the effect with filters, use actual pictures and play with the blending options.

We don't normally put stack photos here, but I'm finding it very difficult to locate some that will show the range, so here are some ideas from iStockPhoto:

[image]
([source](http://www.istockphoto.com/stock-photo-3386652-structured-background.php?st=4942509))

[image]
([source](http://www.istockphoto.com/stock-photo-4836276-blue-green-stained-glass.php?st=4942509))

[image]
([source](http://www.istockphoto.com/stock-photo-4809976-bright-green-stained-glass.php?st=4942509))

Comment: Great – they give me a good starting point. I'm going to play with the various textures here and see what works. If I find any techniques that are worth mentioning I will add them onto the question/comments.